# error: conversion from ‘const char [5]’ to non-scalar type ‘String’ requested

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a class `String` which can be assigned by `operator=`. But the compiler shows an error:

> error: conversion from ‘const char [5]’ to non-scalar type ‘String’ requested

Can anyone help me to fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class String
{
    private:
        char string[];
    public:
        void operator=(const char str[])
        {
            for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
                if (str[i] == '\0') {
                    string[i] = str[i];
                    break;
                } else {
                    string[i] = str[i];
                }
            }
        }

        friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const String& str)
        { 
            output << str.string;
            return output;            
        }
};

int main()
{
    String str1 = "test";
    cout << str1 << endl;
}
```

Comment: `String str1 = "test";` is not `operator=`, it's constructor. You have to add constructor with param `const char str[]` or write `String str1; str1 = "test";`

Answer (score 1):

`String str1 = "test";` does not use `operator=` at all. It is just syntax sugar for `String str1("test");`, which uses a conversion constructor that you have not defined yet, hence the compiler error. You need to add such a constructor.

Also, `char string[];` is not a valid variable declaration for an array. You need to specify a size for the array, and then make sure the class never exceeds that size.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class String {
private:
    char string[256];

public:
    String(const char *str = NULL) {
        if (str) strncpy(string, str, sizeof(string)-1);
        string[sizeof(string)-1] = '\0';
    } 

    String& operator=(const String &str) {
        if (this != &str) {
            memcpy(string, str.string, sizeof(string));
        }
        return *this;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, const String& str) {
        output << str.string;
        return output;
    }
};

int main() {
    String str1 = "test";
    cout << str1 << endl;
}
```

However, in this situation, using a dynamically allocated array makes more sense than using a fixed array. Just be sure to follow the [Rule of 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) for proper memory management.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class String {
private:
    char *string;
    int length;
    int capacity;

public:
    String(const char *str = NULL)
        : string(NULL), length(0), capacity(0)
    {
        if ((str) && (*str != '\0')) {
            length = capacity = strlen(str);
            string = new char[length + 1];
            memcpy(string, str, length + 1);
        }
    }

    String(const String &str)
        : string(NULL), length(0), capacity(0)
    {
        if (str.string) {
            length = capacity = str.length;
            string = new char[length + 1];
            memcpy(string, str.string, length + 1);
        }
    }

    ~String() {
        delete[] string;
    }

    String& operator=(const String &str) {
        if (this != &str) {
            int len = str.length;
            if (capacity >= len) {
                memcpy(string, str.string, len + 1);
            }
            else {
                int cap = int(double(len) * 1.5);
                char *temp = new char[cap + 1];
                memcpy(temp, str.string, len + 1);
                delete[] string;
                string = temp;
                capacity = cap;
            }
            length = len;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, const String& str) {
        if (str.string) {
            output.write(str.string, str.length);
        }
        return output;
    }
};

int main() {
    String str1 = "test";
    cout << str1 << endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a ctor to your class.  You are using the assignment operator to try to construct your String object.  Add this to your class.

```
String(const char str[]) {
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        if (str[i] == '\0') {
            string[i] = str[i];
            break;
        } else {
            string[i] = str[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `string` will have enough space to assign to it? Honestly I'd just make the `string` member a `std::string`

Comment: Thank you! But after I do such thing, I have another trouble.`String str1 = "abc";String str2 = "1234";cout << str1 << endl;` This code will print "1234" but I want "abc".

Comment: @FreezingLeaf you are not allocating any memory for the `string` member